# Can not handle <p> tag in wysiwyg editor

Tags: html, css, tinymce, wysiwyg, root-element

The `<p>` is the default root element of content in most of WYSIWYG editors (I use tinymce) where `<p>` can not contain a block element according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) . When my content is only a single table there is a difference between page source and the rendered elements:

Source of page:

```
   <div class="generalbox">
   <p>
   <table><tr><td>something</td></tr><table>
   </p>
   </div>
```

inspected Element (in both Chrome and Mozila Firefox):

```
    <p></p>
    <div class="generalbox">
    <table><tr><td>something</td></tr><table>
    </div>
    <p></p>
```

This causes a white gap before and after the content. I used the following css rule to omit the gap effect but obviously no success:

```
.generalbox  p:first-of-type {
    margin-top:0;
}

.generalbox  p:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

How should I remove the gap effect? CSS or a server side code or something is WYSIWYG?

Answer (score 1):

Use `:empty` selector to target those WYSIWYG's empty `p` elements:

```
p:empty {
  margin: 0;
}
```

You can also combine with `:not()` to select not empty `p` elements:

```
p:not(:empty) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has an available plugin that allows you to edit the code of your output. Is that option available to you? If not, try this:

```
.generalbox {
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.generalbox + p {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: have html editor button in tinymce but the operators are not professional enough to edit the codes. Besides... Where does 10px come from? is it the default margin of '<p>' element?

Comment: 10px is variable - use whatever margin the empty <p> produces.